# Android SDK Eclipse Issue with Running in Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile, sdk

I am building the layout for an android app. I am not getting any errors when running the app; however, I am getting an error right away when the app launches in the emulator. I am assuming it is a layout rendering fault. Where can I view the error, because no errors are shown in Eclipse.

Main Entry -->

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

ERROR --->

```
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076): Process: com.app.egogo, PID: 1076
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app.egogo/com.app.egogo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.app.egogo.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.egogo-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.app.egogo-1, /system/lib]]
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.app.egogo.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.egogo-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.app.egogo-1, /system/lib]]
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
11-26 02:34:29.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1076):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Can you please mention the line of error you have got?

Comment: added the main java file, it is just the standard that was created by eclipse. Let me know if you need to see any other files?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please!! post the error details what you getting in **LogCat**

Comment: try to clean your project and then run it eclipse-> project -> clean

Comment: I did multiple times. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly then Logcat is the system that would allow you to trouble shoot these kinds of problems in Eclipse.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Once installed you can view it in Eclipse by selecting "Window" from the Eclipse task bar and following this sequence.

Window -> Show View -> Other -> Find and open the Android Folder -> Select Logcat.